# querySelector with 'last-child' returns null when there is an element without class after the classed elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code,
document.querySelector(.list-group-item:last-child) cannot find the element and returns null when there is a li element without the class after the li elements with the class "list-group-item".

my question is that why the querySelector pick up the last li without class ".list-group-item" even though I specify the class name in the querySelector, I think the last li shouldn't be picked up.

Is this the specification of the querySelector?

Thank you for helping!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Item Lister</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="card card-body">
      <h2 class="title">
        Items
      </h2>
      <ul id="items" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Item 1
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Item 2
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Item 3
        </li>
        <!-- Not classed <li> before classed <li>s -->
        <li>Item 3.5</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          Item 4
        </li>
        <!-- Not classed <li> after classed <li>s-->
        <!-- this causes error -->
        <li>Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    /* Ask a Question */
    // TypeError: lastItem is null, when there is a not classed <li> after classed <li>s.

    // select by the class .list-group-item, pseudo class: last-child
    let lastItem = document.querySelector('.list-group-item:last-child');
    lastItem.style.color = 'cyan';



    /*  The code below are references */

    // select by the class .list-group-item
    let item = document.querySelector('.list-group-item');
    item.style.color = 'red';

    // select by the class .list-group-item, pseudo class: nth-child(2)
    let secondItem = document.querySelector('.list-group-item:nth-child(2)');
    secondItem.style.color = 'coral';

    // select by the element <li>, pseudo class: last-child
    let liLastItem = document.querySelector('li:last-child');
    liLastItem.style.color = 'cyan';
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**document.querySelector('.list-group-item:last-child')** gives you error as this is not the last element of **#items**, it's actually **li**.

In order to get the last element of an element with a class, grab all elements with **document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item")**, (*anything with **querySelectorAll** is put in an array*), and loop through this array to retrieve the last element.

*I moved **document.querySelector('.list-group-item:last-child')** at the end or else it would have been overwritten by **document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item")**.*

Hope this helps out.

```js
// select by the class .list-group-item
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");
items.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.style.color = "red";
});

// select by the class .list-group-item, pseudo class: nth-child(2)
let secondItem = document.querySelector(".list-group-item:nth-child(2)");
secondItem.style.color = "coral";

// select by the element <li>, pseudo class: last-child
let liLastItem = document.querySelector("li:last-child");
liLastItem.style.color = "cyan";

// select by the class .list-group-item, pseudo class: last-child
let lastItems = document.querySelectorAll(".list-group-item");
lastItems.forEach(function(lastItem, index) {
  if (index === lastItems.length - 1) {
    lastItem.style.color = "purple";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">
      Items
    </h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Item 1
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Item 2
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Item 3
      </li>
      <!-- Not classed <li> before classed <li>s -->
      <li>Item 3.5</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Item 4
      </li>
      <!-- Not classed <li> after classed <li>s-->
      <!-- this causes error -->
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my question is that why the querySelector pick up the last li without class ".list-group-item" even though I specify the class name in the querySelector, I think the last li shouldn't be picked up. thanks for your answer!

Comment: I noticed that your code will be better if using index of array, lastItems[3].style.color = "purple"; . thanks.

Comment: This is not jQuery specific, it's CSS and it's how it works. :last-child will always look at the last child of the parent container regardless which class/attribute/id you append to it. In regards to your suggestion of 'lastItems[3]', this code will break when the list shrinks/grows as you've defining a fixed index number, and thus will not give you the last item with a class/attribute/id.

Comment: that's great! I understood the :last-child specification now. It looks little bit strange. you considered the flexibility of the code. Your answer is very helpful for me. Thank you so much!